# Add multi image to existed pdf file

Tags: image, pdf, stream, addition

using java ,i made a program can create a pdf depending on OutputStream then i have tried so many time to add multi image to that existed pdf file.
i want made it in the same way (depending on Stream ) is there any way to made it without library like itext or pdfbox??
just using java IO.

Comment: *"to made it without library like itext or pdfbox"* - if you want to create pdfs, there is quite some format specific stuff to do. If you don't want to use an existing library, you'll effectively have to re-implement stuff from therein. Thus, it is possible but you'll have some work ahead of you.

Comment: stuff like what ... could you give me a way to start please

Comment: You need to know the pdf specification. You can start with studying the publicly available copy of ISO 32000-1 [here](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). Simply implement the parts required for your task.